# Adding a handler to an object that calls a global javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm not sure I worded the question the best way possible so I'll show my code example.

I have multiple pages that use the same javascript function. Instead of adding that function to every page, I added it to a .js and imported it in the site master. How can I add a handler to my objects that will call that function, the way I have it doesn't seem to be working.

Edit: I found the problem to be in

```
document.getElementById('<%= PostBackButton.ClientID %>').click();
```

The javascript function does get called correctly and the page does have a PostBackButton asp button, but the getelement is returning null.

```
//chart-ajaxDateSelection.js
function dateSelectionChanged(sender, args) {
  selectedDate = sender.get_selectedDate();

  document.getElementById('<%= PostBackButton.ClientID %>').click();
}

function getSlide()
{
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x=="slide")
    {
      return y;
    }
  }
}
```

My handler:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="OverviewChartStartDateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="OverviewChartStartCal" 
  OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateSelectionChanged" runat="server" 
  TargetControlID="OverviewChartStartDateTextBox">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to call the dateSelectionChanged method when the selected date is changed on the ajax calendar.

Comment: Just to check, if you place `dateSelectionChanged()` inside a `<script></script>` on the master page itself, does your code work then?

Comment: No, I in fact get a server error. I commented out the .js import and added the function in the site master.

Comment: OK. Bascically I needed a baseline to work from, in other words, knwoing whether that JavaScript function works when it's directly on the master page. If it does not work in that scenario, then at least you know it's the function at fault, not that the ".js" file is not being included or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `Javascript` file is not being included properly. As a test, please include the function inside of the page itself, in `<script>` tags:

```
<script>
    function dateSelectionChanged(sender, args) {
        selectedDate = sender.get_selectedDate();  
        document.getElementById('<%= PostBackButton.ClientID %>').click();
    }
</script>
```

Test the date changed event, and if it works, you know your script file wasn't included properly.

If it still doesn't work, the script might have an error. Does the `OnClientDateSelectionChanged` event for the calendar extender have arguments?

Perhaps sender is `null`, and the script is erroring before it gets to your button click event.

Comment: I don't believe that the arguments are the case. I had the dateSelectionFunction on each individual page and I'm trying to generalize it to a global function. It worked fine when it was on each page separately and I copied and pasted exactly what I had into the .js

Comment: Can you use a browser's dev tools (push f12 in chrome, IE, etc) to set a breakpoint in your dateSelectionChanged function to see if it's ever hit? You can also check the console in the dev tools to see what errors show up. It might indicate the missing .js file, or that it can't find the function.

Comment: I somewhat figured out the problem. document.getElementById('<%= PostBackButton.ClientID %>').click(); this line is not working correctly. There is an asp button named PostBackButton, but the global javascript is not invoking the click. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Oh... The code tags (<% %>) will not work in the JS file. The server will not parse the C# inside the tags, so if you look at the output in your browser the file will still show <%= PostBackButton.ClientID %> instead of the id you want. What I would recommend is adding a css class to your button, such as "dateSelectionChangedPostbackButton" and then calling the button click via JQuery and that class selector. $('.dateSelectionChangedPostbackButton').click();

Answer (score 0):

FYI if you have have .net >= 3.5 you can set your controls ClientIDMode to static and access the control with document.getElementById("controlId"); this way you don't have to use the <% %> tags

---

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb_companyEmail" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="input"
                                    type="email" />


document.getElementById("tb_companyEmail");
```